# One-to-one relationship or assignment control in Access?

Tags: database, ms-access

Lets imagine I have two tables. One with an employee and a second one with ID cards. How do I achieve to be able to select one and only one ID card for just one employee? Similarly, this employee is assigned to a position, so no other employee should be able to be assigned to the same position.
I want to make a form where a user fills in an employees personal data and  picks from a drop-down list ID card and a job position that are stored in separate tables. I obviously want to have a relationship among these.
I want to be sure when I create another record I wont be able to pick the same ID card/position twice. How do I achieve this? Is one-to-one relationship the key or some kind of a check whether a particular record is already linked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In table design, Id Card and Position should be Indexed 'Yes(No Duplicates)'.

Comment: Simple answer, perfect solution. Thanks a lot!